# bootstrap ajax content re-appear twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

so, i created an App with bootstrap modal popup.
for example i create 3 step of modal named A, B, and C, in modal A i give a button to continue to modal B, as well as in modal B have a button to continue to modal C.

sometimes when clicking on that button the previous content is loaded instead of next content..for example the file for every modal content is

```
- modal1.html
- modal2.html
- modal3.html
```

in modal 2 i click `continue` button, it should load modal3.html but sometimes instead of loading modal3.html it is loading modal1.html

how to make sure it is working correctly?

EDIT:
script to call modal1/2/3.html

```
$(".ajax-call").on("click", function(){
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(target).modal({
        remote: url
    });
});
```

Trigger

```
<a href="modal1/2/3.html" class="ajax-call" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#MODAL_OR_#SUCCESS_MODAL">
```

Comment: check what your console says, f12 if google chrome and check mistaked there

Comment: nothing error in my console

Comment: if there is no mistake there, then you need to show more code, "sometimes" says nothing

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap when you load the first modal the html will attach to it until you refresh the page, so when you call the second page still content of the first page is displayed. There is a fix for this. Paste the following code in your script. By this your removing the content form the model so each time you call the modal fresh content is loaded.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```